# $route throws an undefined error from inside script setup

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-script-setup

I was wondering why this works:

```html
<template> 
<h1> You are on page {{ $route.params.page }}</h1>
</template>
```

but when I try to access the param from script setup as in

```js
<script setup>
const pageNumber = $route.params.page;
</script>
```

EsLint throws an error for `$route` not being defined.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how variables get accessed from within the template compared to from withing script setup.

I'm well aware of the solution to pass said param as a prop and accessing it with `defineProps` from the component. My question is related to the inner working of Vue. Namely, why variables can be accessed from the template but not from the script.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use these properties in the script setup, you need to import them from their respective modules. For example, if you want to use $route, you need to import useRoute from vue-router and call it in the script setup:

```
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
const route = useRoute()
const pageNumber = route.params.page
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and my apologies for not being more clear in my question. I would like to know how is it possible for the `route.params.page` to be accessed directly from the template. What's so special about the template.

Comment: You're welcome. The reason why you can access the route.params.page directly from the template is because the template has access to some global properties that are injected by Vue, such as $route, $router, $store, etc. These properties are not available in the script setup, because the script setup is compiled as a normal JavaScript module, and does not have access to the Vue instance or the component context.

Comment: Thank you for the terrific answer, if you could update your answer with what you wrote in the comment so I can accept it. Thank you ( :